# decomposition long number to byte and recomposition With FRAM

Tags: variables, eeprom

I'm using Adafruit FRAM for my little project and have some trouble with recomposition of LONG Variable , right now the recomposition on INTEGER it's fine.
Where I'm wrong with recomposition of LONG number? Thank's for reply :D

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Adafruit_FRAM_SPI.h"

/* Example code for the Adafruit SPI FRAM breakout */
uint8_t FRAM_CS = 10;

//Adafruit_FRAM_SPI fram = Adafruit_FRAM_SPI(FRAM_CS);  // use hardware SPI

uint8_t FRAM_SCK = 13;
uint8_t FRAM_MISO = 12;
uint8_t FRAM_MOSI = 11;
//Or use software SPI, any pins!
Adafruit_FRAM_SPI fram = Adafruit_FRAM_SPI(FRAM_SCK, FRAM_MISO, FRAM_MOSI, FRAM_CS);

uint16_t          addr = 0;

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
// for Zero, output on USB Serial console, remove line below if using programming port to program the Zero!
#define Serial SerialUSB
#endif


void setup(void) {
#ifndef ESP8266
  while (!Serial);     // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens
#endif

  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (fram.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Found SPI FRAM");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No SPI FRAM found ... check your connections\r\n");
    while (1);
  }
  int interoDaScrivere = 12345;
  long longDaScrivere = 123456789;
  byte a1 = 0;
  byte a2 = 0;
  byte intPt0 = 0;
  byte intPt1 = 0;
  byte longPt1 = 0;
  byte longPt2 = 0;
  byte longPt3 = 0;
  byte longPt4 = 0;
  a1 = byte(interoDaScrivere);        // si scompone l'intero in 2 byte
  a2 = byte( interoDaScrivere >> 8);
  //decomposition Long

  byte b1 = (longDaScrivere);
  byte b2 = (longDaScrivere >> 8);
  byte b3 = (longDaScrivere >> 16);
  byte b4 = (longDaScrivere >> 24);




  //--------------




  // Read the first byte
  uint8_t test = fram.read8(0x0);
  Serial.print("Restarted "); Serial.print(test); Serial.println(" times");

  // Test write ++
  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(0x0, test + 1);
  fram.writeEnable(false);
  /*
    fram.writeEnable(true);
    fram.write(0x1, (uint8_t *)"FTW!", 5);
    fram.writeEnable(false);
  */

  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(1, a1);
  fram.writeEnable(false);
  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(2, a2);
  fram.writeEnable(false);


  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(3, b1);
  fram.writeEnable(false);
  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(4, b2);
  fram.writeEnable(false);
  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(5, b3);
  fram.writeEnable(false);
  fram.writeEnable(true);
  fram.write8(6, b4);
  fram.writeEnable(false);

  //ricomposizione INT
  int interoRicomposto = 0;
  intPt0 = fram.read8(1);
  intPt1 = fram.read8(2);
  //INT RECOMPOSITION 
  interoRicomposto =  ((intPt1 << 8) | intPt0);
  // ricomposizione LONG
  long longRicomposto = 0;
  longPt1 = fram.read8(3);
  longPt2 = fram.read8(4);
  longPt3 = fram.read8(5);
  longPt4 = fram.read8(6);
 //LONG RECOMPOSITION
  longRicomposto = ((longPt4 << 0) + (longPt3 << 8) + (longPt2 << 16) + (longPt1 << 24));


  Serial.print("A1 F0 ");
  Serial.print(a1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(intPt0);
  Serial.print("A2  F1 ");
  Serial.print(a2);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(intPt1);
  Serial.println(interoRicomposto);



  Serial.print("b1 LongPt1 ");
  Serial.print(b1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(longPt1);
  Serial.print("b2 LongPt2 ");
  Serial.print(b2);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(longPt2);
  Serial.print("b3 LongPt3 ");
  Serial.print(b3);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(longPt3);;
  Serial.print("b4 LongPt4 ");
  Serial.print(b4);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(longPt4);


  Serial.println(longRicomposto);

}

void loop(void) {

}
```

Comment: Looks like you got your shifting backwards in the recombining?

Comment: I'm trying after decomposition in byte to recombine it in a new variable with values readed in the FRAM sorry for my english

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. Look at which portion of the long you are storing in address 3 (for example) and then look at where you are placing what you read from address 3 in the recombined long. Looks to me like you take it from the lower 8 bit, then recombine it into the uppermost 8 bits.

Comment: I'm trying in this line `longRicomposto = ((longPt4 << 0) + (longPt3 << 8) + (longPt2 << 16) + (longPt1 << 24));` but I'm doing something wrong :S thanks for reply

Comment: the arduino write to me 23303 and not 123456789

Comment: I am sorry, I think the language difference is getting in the way. I am telling you what is wrong, and you are just replying with what you have already written. I know what you have already written, I have already read it.

Comment: excuse me for that, can you write an example code I'm really sorry for boring you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one very obvious error in your code: You are writing the `long`
number LSB (least significant byte) first: the LSB goes at address 3 of
the FRAM, while the MSB (most significant byte) goes at address 6. You
reconstruct the number with

```
longRicomposto = ((longPt4 << 0) + (longPt3 << 8) + (longPt2 << 16) + (longPt1 << 24));
```

which puts `longPt1` (contents of address 3) as the most significant
byte. Thus you are swapping all the bytes around.

Then there is a more subtle error. `longPt1` is a `byte`. According to the
C++ promotion rules, it is implicitly promoted to `int` before any
arithmetic or logical operation. But since an `int` is 16-bits, you are
shifting *all the bits out* when you do `longPt1 << 24`. You should cast
the numbers to a 32-bit type before shifting, as follows:

```c++
long longRicomposto = (uint32_t) longPt1 <<  0
                    | (uint32_t) longPt2 <<  8
                    | (uint32_t) longPt3 << 16
                    | (uint32_t) longPt4 << 24;
```

Note that I am casting to an *unsigned* type. Shifting a 1 into the bit
sign of an integer is undefined behavior in C++: the shift must be done
with an unsigned type, *then*, if needed, cast to a signed type.

Comment: > You should cast the numbers to a 32-bit type before shifting, as follows: it is advisable to use brackets liberally in cases like that. don't leave any doubts there as to how you want the shifts to be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is actual a member function in the [Adafruit_FRAM_SPI](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FRAM_SPI/blob/master/Adafruit_FRAM_SPI.h#L66) library that solves all of this. There is no need for all this shifting.

```
int interoDaScrivere = 12345;
long longDaScrivere = 123456789;

fram.write(1, (const uint8_t*) &interoDaScrivere, sizeof(interoDaScrivere));
fram.write(3, (const uint8_t*) &longDaScrivere, sizeof(longDaScrivere));
```

And

```
fram.read(1, (uint8_t*) &interoDaScrivere, sizeof(interoDaScrivere));
fram.read(3, (uint8_t*) &longDaScrivere, sizeof(longDaScrivere));
```

Cheers!

PS: Might need to adjust depending on the number of bytes/bits and address.

Answer (score 0):

Let's cut out all the rubbish from your code and just look at the relevant lines:

```
byte b1 = (longDaScrivere);
byte b2 = (longDaScrivere >> 8);
byte b3 = (longDaScrivere >> 16);
byte b4 = (longDaScrivere >> 24);

fram.write8(3, b1);
fram.write8(4, b2);
fram.write8(5, b3);
fram.write8(6, b4);

longPt1 = fram.read8(3);
longPt2 = fram.read8(4);
longPt3 = fram.read8(5);
longPt4 = fram.read8(6);

longRicomposto = ((longPt4 << 0) + (longPt3 << 8) + (longPt2 << 16) + (longPt1 << 24));
```

If we now compress it even more by removing the fram stuff and just assigning direct from b? to the equivalent longPt? you can see even better what is happening:

```
byte b1 = (longDaScrivere);
byte b2 = (longDaScrivere >> 8);
byte b3 = (longDaScrivere >> 16);
byte b4 = (longDaScrivere >> 24);

longPt1 = b1;
longPt2 = b2;
longPt3 = b3;
longPt4 = b4;

longRicomposto = ((longPt4 << 0) + (longPt3 << 8) + (longPt2 << 16) + (longPt1 << 24));
```

Now if we remove the b? variables completely and just assign direct to longPt? we get:

```
longPt1 = (longDaScrivere);
longPt2 = (longDaScrivere >> 8);
longPt3 = (longDaScrivere >> 16);
longPt4 = (longDaScrivere >> 24);

longRicomposto = ((longPt4 << 0) + (longPt3 << 8) + (longPt2 << 16) + (longPt1 << 24));
```

And if we then split the last line up so it looks more like the first block:

```
longPt1 = (longDaScrivere);
longPt2 = (longDaScrivere >> 8);
longPt3 = (longDaScrivere >> 16);
longPt4 = (longDaScrivere >> 24);

longRicomposto  = (longPt4 << 0);
longRicomposto |= (longPt3 << 8);
longRicomposto |= (longPt2 << 16);
longRicomposto |= (longPt1 << 24);
```

Hopefully from that it is now clear where you have gone wrong.

You take the lowest 8 bits `(longDaScrivere)` and shift them 24 places to the left (`(longPt1 << 24)`), and apply that to the recombined long.

In effect, you start with 4 bytes `ABCD` and reverse them through bit shifting - 0 goes to 24, 8 to 16, 16 to 8 and 24 to 0, to end up with `DCBA`.